# using HTML 5 features over Phone Gap

Tags: android, html, cordova, local-storage, sessionstorage

I am making a website in HTML5/CSS3 and would be using features like a Local Storage and 
session Storage

later on I also need to develop an Android app (NOT mobile website) for the same website using PhoneGap.

so, Is it possible to still use the session storage and local storage features of HTML5 in the native android App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Storage can be used in PhoneGap. Session Storage is also supported.

For using Local Storage,go through the documentation:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

window.sessionStorage provides the same interface, but is cleared between app launches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` in your PhoneGap app no problem. Naturally the `sessionStorage` data will only exist for the length of the session in question and will be destroyed when the app is exiting.

The `localStorage` data will remain of course but will be tied to the app only. You will not be able to access the same `localStorage` data between the website and the PhoneGap app. I'm sure you know this but am just pointing it out.

Answer (score -2):

Just done this in Uni and (assuming) you're on about PHP/MySQL sessions?

The answer is unfortunately not, you'd have to use XML in order to be able to replicate sort of thing.